Implementing Distributed Tracing with Azure AppInsights using OpenTelemetry in .NET
I've been working on implementing distributed tracing in my .NET 8 application using OpenTelemetry. I've referred to the article : https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/introduction-to-distributed-tracing-with-opentelemetry-in-dotnet and I've been successful in viewing the metrics and tracing information using the Jaeger UI.
However, I'm looking to extend this concept and use Azure Application Insights instead of Jaeger UI. My goal is to interpret the tracing and metrics information in Azure AppInsights.
Here is the code I've been using to configure OpenTelemetry:
private static void ConfigureOpenTelemetry(WebApplicationBuilder builder, ConfigurationManager config)
{
    var appConfig = builder.Services.BindValidateReturn<DemoCloudServiceOptions>(config);
    builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();
    builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry(appConfig.AppInsightsConnString);

    builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService("MyApp"))
    .WithMetrics(metrics =>
    {
        metrics
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation();

        metrics.AddMeter("MyApp");

        metrics.AddOtlpExporter();
    })
    .WithTracing(tracing =>
    {
        tracing
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation();

        tracing.AddOtlpExporter();
    });

    builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(logging => logging.AddOtlpExporter());
}

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can you please share your .csproj file

Look at rhe Azure Monitor SDK for OpenTelemetry. It will give you a specific exporter to use as AppInsights/Azure Monitor doesn't support OTLP.

@Harshitha - Thanks for your reply. I have use the below nuget packages :
Automatic tracing, metrics
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting
Telemetry data exporter
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol
Instrumentation packages
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.EntityFrameworkCore
Install-Package OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.StackExchangeRedis

What is the issue with your code you are using now?

Using Jaeger UI, I can search all the details using the Service dropdown. I setup OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317. I wanted to know where to search the details in case of Azure AppInsights.

Check the Transaction Serach in Application Insights.

You have not added Connection String / Instrumentation key of Application Insights.

I have added it : builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry(appConfig.AppInsightsConnString);

Can you please share your .csproj with package versions in the code.You can edit it in the above question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am able to log Open telemetry to Application Insights.
I have followed this MSDoc to configure Opentelemetry in .NET Core 8 Application.
Use the configuration in appsettings.json file as mentioned here in my SOThread
My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/****/providers/microsoft.insights/components/SampleAppInsights</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <UserSecretsId>****</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Thanks @Rahul Rai for the clear explanation.
My Program.cs file:
using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using System.Diagnostics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var conn = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"];

builder.Logging.ClearProviders()
    .AddOpenTelemetry(loggerOptions =>
    {
        loggerOptions
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MyApp"))         
            .AddAzureMonitorLogExporter(options =>
                options.ConnectionString = conn)     
            .AddConsoleExporter();

        loggerOptions.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
        loggerOptions.IncludeScopes = true;
        loggerOptions.ParseStateValues = true;
    });

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});

var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
 
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


Even the below code worked for me.

 builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithTracing(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        builder.AddConsoleExporter();
        builder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MyApp"));
        builder.AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(options =>
           {
               options.ConnectionString = conn;
           });
        builder.AddConsoleExporter();
    });

Local Traces:
Activity.TraceId:            729cc92ac67fe948aaeeaaa250af5431
Activity.SpanId:             2b2e1eb570dbfe44
Activity.TraceFlags:         Recorded
Activity.ActivitySourceName: Microsoft.AspNetCore
Activity.DisplayName:        GET
Activity.Kind:               Server
Activity.StartTime:          2024-05-24T14:51:20.6775264Z
Activity.Duration:           00:00:00.0011907
Activity.Tags:
    server.address: localhost
    server.port: 7285
    http.request.method: GET
    url.scheme: https
    url.path: /_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js
    network.protocol.version: 2
    user_agent.original: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0
    http.response.status_code: 200

Application Insights Transaction Search:

Logs:


You can see the local telemetry TraceID  is shown in ApplicationInsights as Operation ID.



@santosh kumar patro - Have you tried the above sol?
